# Why two same string but concatenated differently have different results in shell context called with python?

Tags: python, string, shell

I want to start a cygwin command from my python script and my command is in the variable `params`. I have multiple ways to write the string :

```
import os
import subprocess

params = r'"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -c ' + r"""'ls "C:\Users"'"""

print(subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True))
```

This works just fine, however this :

```
import os
import subprocess

params = r"""'C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe' --login -c 'ls "C:\Users"'"""

print(subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True))
```

Returns `non-zero exit status 1` while it is supposed to be exactly the same string. To check the difference I run this script :

```
print(repr(r"""'C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe' --login -c 'ls "C:\Users"'"""))
print(repr(r'"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -c ' + r"""'ls "C:\Users"'"""))
```

Returns :

```
'\'C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe\' --login -c \'ls "C:\\Users"\''
'"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe" --login -c \'ls "C:\\Users"\''
```

I'm not sure how to interpret that frankly speaking neither do I understand how to fix my monolitic string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first string wraps bash.exe in double quotes:

```
"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe"
```

The second one wraps it in single quotes.

```
'C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe'
```

Double quotes is what you want. Or no quotes, since the path has no spaces.

```
params = r""""C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -c 'ls "C:\Users"'"""
params = r"""C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -c 'ls "C:\Users"'"""
```

Comment: yeah realized that just after posting \*_\* but I can't do four """" in a row at the end I have to swap the signs to make it work

Comment: well `r""""C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -c "ls 'C:\Users'""""` returns `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` on the very last `"`

Comment: Don't use four at the end, just three. Think of it as `r"""` in the front and `"""` in the back. Those are the delimiters. The fourth `"` in the front is part of the string contents, it's not a delimiter that needs to be matched.